# Can't select text using keyboard in Visual Studio Code

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code, key-binding

For some reason, I can't select text using the keyboard in Visual Studio Code (version 1.45.1 on macOS 10.15.4).

If I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>, the cursor moves right, but the text isn't selected.

If I:

- go to Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts,
- select the "Recording keys" options, then
- press <kbd>Shift</kbd> then <kbd>right</kbd>

this is what happens:

When I press shift, I see "Shift+" appear in the box; but, then when I add the right key, I get "right" instead of the expected "Shift+right".

This happens after a restart -- even if I disable all plugins.

It's also inconsistent:  Most of the time it doesn't work; but, sometimes it does.  One thing is consistent:  If I try to do a column edit (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd>) then <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>right</kbd> stops working.

Any idea what could be wrong / misconfigured?

---

settings file:

```
{
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
    "java.configuration.checkProjectSettingsExclusions": false,
    "[java]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "redhat.java"
    },
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "[erb]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "aliariff.vscode-erb-beautify",
    },
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"

    },
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "maven.executable.path": "/opt/local/bin/mvn",
    "workbench.settings.useSplitJSON": true,
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false,
    "[javascriptreact]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
    "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
    "prettier.arrowParens": "always",
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.eslink": true
    },
    "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
    "prettier.jsxBracketSameLine": true,
    "javascript.format.semicolons": "remove",
    "javascript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single",
    "typescript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": true,
   "javascript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": true,
    "cSpell.enableFiletypes": [
        "erb"
    ],
    "java.requirements.JDK11Warning": false,
    "java.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true
}
```